# Solve for simultaneous second order ODE for bioreactor with different stages using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, ode

I am trying to solve simultaneous second order differential equations to find the concentration of a tracer (molecule) at different stages of a bioreactor. The stages are arranged in series.

**Context:** Bioreactor that we are working with, is a Rotating Biological Contractor. Here is an [example.](https://images.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fixedfilmforum.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2012%2F02%2F2.3.1-RBC-Schematic.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fixedfilmforum.com%2Fq-and-a-forum%2Frotating-biological-contactors%2F&docid=Y8jStdW_y4-uTM&tbnid=-7jnKCVdg7y7cM%3A&vet=1&w=500&h=200&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim) The tracer molecule is injected at the first stage at time t=0 and our objective is to find how the concentration of the tracer molecule varies with respect to time in each stage.

The second order ODE that we are working with can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNeep.jpg

I tried to simplify the equation for 4 stages (2nd and 3rd pic in imgur album) and have tried to solve it using MATLAB. Here is the code for it:

```
 P2 = 1; P3 = 5; C0 = 30; P4 = 2;

f = @(t,x)[x(2); (C0+P4*x(7)-x(1)-P3*x(2))/P2;
          x(4); (x(1)-x(3)-P3*x(4))/P2;
          x(6); (x(3)-x(5)-P3*x(6))/P2;
          x(8); (x(5)-x(7)-P3*x(8))/P2];

t= linspace(0,40); init = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];

[t Y] = ode45(f,t,init);

plot(t,Y(:,1),'r-',t,Y(:,3),'b-',t,Y(:,5),'k-',t,Y(:,7),'m-')

legend('C1','C2','C3','C4')
```

Our aim is to know how the concentration varies in the 4th stage. It is supposed to look like this [Residence time distribution](https://images.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fumich.edu%2F~elements%2Fcourse%2Flectures%2Fthirteen%2Fpics%2Flec31-06.gif&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fumich.edu%2F~elements%2Fcourse%2Flectures%2Fthirteen%2Findex.htm&docid=DkHuxjje3PwFpM&tbnid=pVLcpSTOxQ2ZNM%3A&vet=1&w=522&h=308&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim) or something similar.

I need to know whether its possible to use "for loop" for "n" stages in series and solve the equation. Ideally, only inputs should be no. of stages, time interval, initial concentration and constants. Assume whatever values for constants, initial conc. and time interval.

Could someone please guide me through solving this? I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Your question is well written. The math seems clear and implementation with matlab shouldn't be a problem. Nevertheless, I can't guide you through your whole problem. That would be too broad of a question for SO. I can point you to some resources though and help you with some example code. I see you using `ode45`. Are you able to use `ode45` for simple 1-dimensional cases?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I will assume by 1-dimensional you would mean first order differential equations. In that case, yes, I was successfully able to model batch fermentation. The model equation looks like [this](https://images.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.scielo.br%2Fimg%2Frevistas%2Fbjce%2Fv30n1%2Fa12for3-5.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.scielo.br%2Fscielo.php%3Fscript%3Dsci_arttext%26pid%3DS0104-66322013000100012&docid=nw8jRqlfw7TXoM&tbnid=R8APFbBQ40wayM%3A&vet=1&w=345&h=169&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim)

Comment: @AkshayAcharya: Just to make sure I understand your question correctly, you are getting the correct solution for the ODEs, and you're trying to generalize it for `n` stages instead of `4`. Correct?

Comment: @AkshayAcharya: by 1-dimensional, I mean, when applying to natural sciences, only 1 time-dependent variable. In your batch fermentation example, the function is 3-dimensional. As for order of DEs, to my best recollections, there is no issue with higher order DEs in matlab. But whether `ode45` will behave well with higher order DEs is another matter. I don't quite get where you are stuck at this point. (Would try your code but need to wait till later when I get home and access to matlab.) I have the same question as @Aziz now.

Comment: @Aziz Yes, I am trying to generalise for n stages. I am not sure if my code is correct because the conc. of tracer in 3rd stage becomes 0 which in reality is not the case. It could be due to initial conditions or parameters, but at t=0 all the conc = 0 and I tried messing around changing parameters and still was getting conc in 3rd stage as 0.

Comment: @Argyll I've seen many tutorials where in you convert 2nd order DE to set of 1st order DE's and solve using 'ode45' which is what I've done. But the problem is here, the conc. depends on no. of stages as well as the time but there is no dC/dn term. Which is why I need help in generalizing it for 'n' stages. I appreciate you trying to help me out. You can take your time. Thank you, both of you!

Comment: @AkshayAcharya: It's easy to see the pattern of the equations and generalize them to `n` stages. I think there is a typo in your code: stage 3 equation is correct in the notes but incorrect in the code (should be `x(5)`, not `x(4)`) Can you confirm that is a typo?

Comment: Also another typo in stage 4, it should be `x(8)` instead of `x(7)`. Once you confirm that your code works correctly and produces the correct solution, you can generalize it to `n` stages.

Comment: @Aziz I am really sorry for such ignorant mistakes. I have corrected the code and will edit the same in original post. Here is the output that I [get](https://imgur.com/a/AHj2j)

Comment: @Aziz Without considering the pattern of equations, is it possible to implement ode45 for solving the two ODE's that I have posted in my problem picture (imgur album). Also, would need a separate condition for the first stage.

Comment: Does [LutzL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3088138/lutzl)'s answer solve the problem? As for your question to @Aziz, yes.

Comment: @Argyll Yes it does indeed work and I am grateful. However, I want to solve the first 2 ODE's like I mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: Certainly. But first, in your n=1 case, why do you have p_4 c_4 at the end?

Comment: @Argyll The concentration of the molecule leaving the nth stage is fed back into the first stage. Because my example had 4 stages, c4 is fed back to the first stage. Hope it helps.

Comment: Then you would need to solve for all c_n simultaneously. Were you able to convert them into a system of first order ODEs?

Comment: @Argyll Yes I took n=4 and converted them into 8 first order ODE's. You can see it in imgur album in question (2nd and 3rd pic)

Comment: I would like to keep distance from math when dealing with SO questions. The conversion looks fine. This goes back to the earlier question. You know how to use `odefun` and use it for multidimensional case. You know how to deal with higher order ODEs. Is your problem recognizing a pattern in the ODE in terms of number of stages `n`? It doesn't seem like you need any dC/dn term.

Comment: And just so you know, Matlab has quite a bit of tools for modeling dynamical systems. See [this tutorial](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/gs/define-system.html) as an example. I don't think there is anything that can help you generating the corresponding DEs based on the number of stages. I imagine you have to manually define those stages with simulink tools. But if you become versed in simulink, maybe it will help you check answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the anonymous/lambda definition of `f`, use a more traditional function which allows you to employ loops.

```
n = 4
function dotx = f(t,x)
    dotx = zeros(2*n,1)
    dotx(1) = x(2);
    dotx(2) = (C0+P4*x(7)-x(1)-P3*x(2))/P2
    for k = 2:n
        dotx(2*k-1) = x(2*k)
        dotx(2*k) = (x(2*k-3)-x(2*k-1)-P3*x(2*k))/P2
    end
end

init = zeros(2*n,1)
```

One may have to change row/column format for `x, dotx`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I changed the line `dotx = zeros(1,2*n)` to `dotx = zeros(2*n,1)` and it is **working**. I presume this is what you meant by changing row/column format for `x`

Comment: Yes. As that is also true in scilab, I changed it in the answer.